# What is the NAT traversal technique used by bitcoin

Tags: network, peers

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=30947.msg23736281#msg23736281 says that

1. **incoming port can be opened** or
2. UPnP enabled.

Is this incoming port opened on the NAT device so that all incoming messages coming to that port are relayed to my host?

EDIT: More resources about the topic https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#enabling-connections and https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#network-configuration

The second resource says: "If Bitcoin Core can’t automatically configure your router to open port 8333, you will need to manually configure your router."

Is this automatic opening mentioned actually UPnP way?

And manually configuring the router actually bullet 1 mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, that's what it's talking about, but it isn't something that Bitcoin Core does itself.  The post is just saying that you should manually configure your NAT device to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this automatic opening mentioned actually UPnP way?

Yes. UPnP is disabled by default in Bitcoin Core due to some vulnerabilities in UPnP. You can enable it by going to `Settings > Options > Network` and checking `Map port using UPnP`

> And manually configuring the router actually bullet 1 mentioned above?

Yes.