# How does bitcoin core establish a peer to peer network

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers

I've tried to look for an answer to this online and haven't found any. My question is: how does bitcoin establish a peer to peer network. Establishing a centralized network with a server in the middle between all clients is trivial. However, establishing a fully peer to peer network isn't that easy. This is mostly due to NATs and Firewalls. How does bitcoin core get around NATs and Firewalls. Does it use holepunching, and, if so, is there a central server that dynamically updates public and private Ip/ports? I guess I would just like to know how the peer to peer network is established.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Bitcoin clients find each other?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/how-do-bitcoin-clients-find-each-other) and [What is the NAT traversal technique used by bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/61546/13866)

Comment: Not really. None of the two explain how bitcoin deals with NATs and firewalls. Or what set of protocols from the OSI model does it use to communicate with other peers. Does it use http? Websockets? Does it use it's own application layer protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bitcoin P2P protocol is an application-specific layer over TCP/IP.

If a node does not have an open port by themselves, they can only make outgoing connections. Node software uses things like UPnP to request NATs to open ports, but if that fails, a node's connections will be unidirectional.

Comment: If a node's connection becomes unidirectional, then it can only make requests to other nodes with public IPs and Ports. Is that how unidirectionally connected nodes update their blockchain?

Comment: Could you briefly elaborate on what UPnP is please.

Comment: Yes, but the protocol is symmetric. So if a node can only make outbound connections, that is still a fully-featured connection between two nodes - it doesn't matter who established the connection. There isn't a "server" and "client" side to the connection.

Comment: But it does, ultimately, resemble a client server architecture in the sense that nodes that are behind NATs, just like clients in a client server architecture, can only make outgoing transactions but cannot listen to incoming transactions. It's similar to a REST API.

Comment: Yes, in terms of connectivity you are right, but not in terms of functionality. If A connects B, then it will be both the case that A requests things from B, and B requests things from A.

Comment: based on my knowledge, bitcoin core connections aren't technically symmetric and there are comments in code that prove this, like on GETADDR message that gets ignored if the sender is a peer different than inbound. So basically a peer that can only have outbound connection will never send other peers its known addresses (this is an example but I think there are other cases where there aren't asymmetric behaviors)

Comment: Sure, and transaction relay also works slightly differently in both directions. Still, both parties will learn each other's transactions and blocks.

Comment: let me go a bit OT @PieterWuille to show gratitude for the effort you put in cryptospace and your attitude you keep showing to help people since long time